# invoke __dopostback inside IE via powershell

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, powershell, vbscript

I'm writing powershell script that simulates actions performed by user on the page.
I have a problem with performing click on a button. Page has form and inside button that saves changes to database:

```
input type="button" onClick="__doPostBack('someIdentifier','SAVE')" value="Save changes"
```

I need to invoke that from the client side. Problem is that button it self has id="" and tag="" so the following doesn't work:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application";
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate("http://myTestedPage.com");
$doc = $ie.Document;

#doesn't work
$save = $doc.getElementByID("")
#doesn't work neither
$save = $doc.getElementsByTagName("");

#so how to call
$save.click();
```

both getElementbyID and getElementsByTagName just perform some operations but only effect they have is my CPU usage jumping to max.

I was thinking about getting `elements[]` of the form and finding button there but it doesn't neither (effects like in previous case).

Is there some other (brilliant) way to do that (that obviously I'm not aware of)? I would need something like `InvokeScript`

```
webBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser()
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript(@"__doPostBack", new object[] {@"someIdentifier", @"SAVE"});
```

but I need to use instance of IE manipulated by powershell (or other scripting/programming language, maybe VBScript?), not .NET standalone app.

Comment: BTW accepted answer doesn't answer the question, but it answers the question behind the question. So now I don't need to invoke __postback directly... but if someone knows how to do that, please share the knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2nd attempt**

The following code searches for and clicks on all `input` elements that have a `value="Save changes"` attribute.

I had to read the attribute's `nodeValue` property dynamically since it wasn't exposed in the interface.

```
function getProperty ([System.__ComObject] $obj, [string] $prop)
{
    [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember($prop, [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, $obj, $null)
}

$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate('e:\scratch\h.html')
$doc = $ie.Document

$inputElts = $doc.getElementsByTagName('input')
foreach ($elt in $inputElts)
{
    $a = $elt.getAttributeNode('value')
    if ($a -and (getProperty $a 'nodeValue') -eq 'Save changes')
    {
        $elt.Click()
    }
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertMsg() {alert("Button was clicked!")}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="alertMsg()"  value="Save changes" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well that's the point - both TAG and ID are empty for this button (I've mentioned this in my question). So I can't (or I don't know how) catch button object therefore I'm looking for a way to invoke __dopostback that is executed on button click.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see that. You should provide minimal but *complete* code in order to reduce the chance of misunderstanding. Your input element BTW does have a tag. It is "input". Unfortunately the collection returned by getElementsByTagName("input") doesn't have any useful methods or properties ...

Comment: ... Strangely, most of the DOM objects from IE in PowerShell have incomplete interfaces. That will make the job harder. I may have another look later.

Comment: Hey. Did that code actually worked for you? First of all should there be getPropety in loop? My PS is throwing errors. If you meant $a.getPropety('nodeValue') this object doesn't contain this method. If it was supposed to be get-member $a 'nodeValue' then this object doesn't contain this property.

Comment: Yes of course it worked for me. getProperty is a function I wrote. It is at the top of the code. I needed it access the nodeValue property, as I explained. You can look up nodeValue here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752509(VS.85).aspx . As I said, nodeValue isn't visible. ...

Comment: ... that's why I had to use InvokeMember to get it. The reason it is invisible is too complicated to explain here.

"My PS is throwing errors" is not helpful.

Comment: I dunno why I skipped function at the beginning. Anyway it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Yoosiba,
  I have been struggling with a similar issue. I can get you the element name. Run this code from the CLI. Then use tab key to highlight the element you want to click.
  Then you can type "$doc.activeelement" to get the properties of the element you want. Remember you can get elements by tagname, name or ID. I had to do a sort like this to get the element I wanted:

$link=$doc.getElementsByTagName("A") | where {$_.sourceIndex -like "256"}

You can probably do something similar.
Dave M